# Why HTML rand command keep produce more than 0.5

Tags: javascript, html, random

I was coding to understand how html work but I could not understand the `Math.random()` function fully.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Value:<br> <p id="Value"> 0 </p>
<div>
</div>

<p>Click the button to increase the value.</p>

<button onclick="increase()"+",this.blur()" id="demp" style="position:relative; left: 500px; top: 80px; width: 64px; height: 64px;">Increase</button>

<script>
function increase() {
    var x = document.getElementById("Value").innerHTML;
    var increased = parseInt(x,10) + parseInt(1,10);
    document.getElementById("Value").innerHTML = increased;
}

function change(){
    var num = 0;
    window.setInterval(function(){
    var speedx= Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5);
    var speedy= Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5);
    document.getElementById("demp").style.left= parseInt(document.getElementById("demp").style.left, 10) + parseInt(speedx,10) +"px"; 
    document.getElementById("demp").style.top= parseInt(document.getElementById("demp").style.top, 10) + parseInt(speedy,10) +"px"; 
    }, 10)
}
window.onload = function start() {
    change();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created a button which is changing it's position according to `Math.random()` value. I refresh the page like 30 times and my button always going up and left. That means `math.random()` function produce greater then 0.5
Can you explain why it doesn't produce real random numbers and how can I create a real random number?

Comment: It's just bias. `Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5)` chooses values between -5 and 4, so the result is much more likely to be negative than positive. Try multiplying by 11 instead.

Comment: because of the minus 5, `Math.random() * 10` is a float, say `3.171433220370915` then math floor rounds it down, so now it,s 3, then you take away 5, so it's now -2. style left -2 and style top -2 moves it up and left,

Comment: There's something odd in the button's click handler: `onclick="increase()"+",this.blur()"` Intentional?

Comment: actually you have `60% against 40%` chance that your button won't go `down` and `right.`

Comment: @Teemu I did it due to I dont want my button to be colored when I press but I couldn't. I should delete this code.

Comment: @Juhana but why isn't that 0<number<1 so 0<number*10<10 then -5<number*10-5<5

Comment: `Math.floor()` makes sure that you can never have +5.

Comment: Eh... JS sentences are separated by `;`. Ex. `onclick="increase(); this.blur();"` ... Though it won't prevent button highlighting on click. Use `hover` and `active` pseudo-classes instead.

Comment: @Teemu that worked thank you